# Stopping Button Click Function in C# Winfoms

Tags: c#, winforms, onclick

I have a Save Button that grabs information and stores it in SQL from a Winform.
The issue I'm having is that if you click the save button, it still stores blank information in the database.  I don't want this.  Here's my code.  Keep in mind, the actual saving, updating, getting data work perfectly.

```
        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtLocalSourcePath.Text != null)
        {
            if (ResourceKey == 0)
            {
                ConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Dev"].ConnectionString;
                GetData(ConnString);
                InsertData(ConnString);
                GetData(ConnString);
                lblInsertNewRecord.Visible = true;
                lblInsertNewRecord.Text = String.Format("You have inserted a new record at {0}", System.DateTime.Now);
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateData();
                GetData(ConnString);
                lblInsertNewRecord.Visible = true;
                lblInsertNewRecord.Text = String.Format("Updated Record at {0}", System.DateTime.Now );
            }
            ClearData();
        }
        else
        {
            lblInsertNewRecord.Visible = true;
            lblInsertNewRecord.Text = "Cannot add record.  Please select file.";
        }
    }
```

I have tried these options:
[stopping a function executed on a winform button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259676/stopping-a-function-executed-on-a-winform-button-click)
[How to cancel any event in winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672890/how-to-cancel-any-event-in-winforms)
[How to cancel winform button click event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24899727/how-to-cancel-winform-button-click-event)

Comment: You probably want to try `if (txtLocalSourcePath.Text != null && txtLocalSourcePath.Text.Length > 0)` (Edited: fixed `.Length` to `.Text.Length`)

Comment: Okay, let me try that.  Thanks for the quick response

Comment: I can't do .Length because it's a DevExpress.XtraEditors.ButtonEdit

Comment: Agree with @EBrown. You can shorten it, though, to: `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLocalSourcePath.Text))` [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm sorry, `txtLocalSourcePath.Text.Length`

Comment: And @basher's solution is effective as well. The problem is that the `.Text` property is *NOT* actually **null**, but is instead simply a blank (`""`) string.

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thank you!  You should create an answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: Done, and not a problem. We all miss logic sometimes.

Comment: I would suggest using `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(...)` instead of `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(...)` ... That way you you won't still write to the DB in the case of spaces being input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to try `if (txtLocalSourcePath.Text != null && txtLocalSourcePath.Text.Length > 0)`, or the solution proposed by basher:

`if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLocalSourcePath.Text))`

The `.Text` property is *NOT* actually **null**, but instead just a blank (`""`) string.

Edit: Russ Wilson's recommendation in comments is also handy: `if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtLocalSourcePath.Text))`, which guarantees that the string is not just spaces/tabs/etc.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you again for the quick response!

Comment: @KevinFischer Mark as solved to get it out of the queue, please. :)

Comment: trying.  I have to wait 2 minutes

Comment: Aha, I was unaware of that.